# Measure over one dimension conditional on value of another dimension

Tags: mdx

I am new to MDX and have a problem I have been struggling with.

I have essentially the below table (*with obviously more dimensions behind the scenes in my cube*). If an ID was new yesterday it will appear in the **cube** with date **T-1** and Category "**New**", it will also have a different set of values for date **T** and Category "**Old**". If it was Old yesterday it will be old today and have a different value.

I can get the sum of values for "**New**" IDs on the **T-1** slice, but cannot get the sum of values on the Today (T) slice for the IDs which were "**New**" yesterday (*and therefore are old today*) - I.e. the value today of the IDs which were new yesterday.

```
|   ID    |  Category  | Date | Value |
|---------|------------|------|-------|
|    1    |   New      | T-1  |   a   |
|    1    |   Old      | T    |   b   |
|    2    |   Old      | T-1  |   c   |
|    2    |   Old      | T    |   d   |
|    3    |   New      | T-1  |   e   |
|    3    |   Old      | T    |   f   |
```

If the data was in a flat table I think I could SQL query it, but I'm a bit stumped when it comes to the MDX. Thanks.

EDIT:

The MDX below gives me the sum of the **"Old"** IDs. I think I somehow need to create a new measure which looks at the PrevMember of ID along the date slice and checks whether it was new, and if so then assign the current measure of the ID that this new measure - but I do not know how to do it...

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY (
    [Date].Members
            ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY (
    [Measures].[Value.SUM]
            ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE (
[Category].&[Old]
    )
```

EDIT2:
Using SouravA's answer I have got my code working using the below code.

```
WITH 
SET NewIDs AS
    INTERSECT(NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old]))
        , NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD]))
        )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children
    ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY([NewIDs]
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE [Measures].[Value]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you exactly want to see in output?

Comment: The output should essentially just be b+f, the sum of values for those IDs which were new yesterday

Comment: Can you add your successful MDX and also the MDX you’ve tried for bit you are struggling with

Comment: Request you to post a new question with the added requirements.

Comment: I have done so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980765/slicing-over-a-named-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? (Added comments in code below)

```
WITH SET NewYesterdayOldToday ///Get all such Ids which were new yesterday but are old today
AS
INTERSECT(
NonEmpty(
    [YourTable].[Id].[All].MEMBERS,
    [YourTable].[Category].&[Old] * [YourTable].[Date]. &[T])
,
NonEmpty(
    [YourTable].[Id].[All].MEMBERS,
    [YourTable].[Category].&[New] * [YourTable].[Date]. &[T-1])
)

MEMBER TotalValue AS ///Getting the sum of values corresponding to those Ids which are "NewYesterdayOldToday" today
(
NewYesterdayOldToday, [YourTable].[Date]. &[T], [Measures].[Value.SUM]
)

SELECT TotalValue 
    ON 0
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: Thanks SouravA - this answers my question as asked.