# Slicing over a named set

Tags: mdx

This is a follow up question to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880020/measure-over-one-dimension-conditional-on-value-of-another-dimension?noredirect=1#comment86974402_49880020)

I have the following working code:

```
WITH 
SET NewIDs AS
    INTERSECT(NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old]))
        , NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD]))
        )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children
    ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY([NewIDs]
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE [Measures].[Value]
```

However I would like to have another dimension on rows, not the ID (let's call it Dim1)

I have tried the below, but it does not work (as I don't think you can slice on named sets)

```
WITH 
SET NewIDs AS
    INTERSECT(NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old]))
        , NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD]))
        )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children
    ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY([Dim1].Children
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE [Measures].[Value]
, [NewIDs]
```

EDIT:
Some further clarity. I usually aggregate the Value measure, and look at it in a table of Dim2 on columns and Dim1 on rows (this will include *all* IDs). However now I want to just have this but sliced only on the [NewIDs] set.

EDIT2:
Using the below code *almost* solves my question, but on rows I have an unwanted column where every value is **NewIDs** ideally which I would like not to have.

```
WITH 
SET NewIDs AS
    INTERSECT(NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old]))
        , NonEmpty([ID].Children, CROSSJOIN([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD]))
        )
MEMBER [ID].[NewIDs] AS
       Aggregate([NewIDs])
SELECT 
NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children
    ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY([ID].[NewIDs] * [Dim1].Children
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE [Measures].[Value]
```

Comment: Is there any relation defined between Dim1 or Dim2 against the dimension that contains the ID hierarchy?

Comment: Dim1 and Dim2 are single level hierarchies with no relation.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the premise here. What I understood so far is that Dim1, Dim2 and Id fall under the same dimension as different hierarchies. Please correct me if that's not the case.

Comment: Sorry - they are all difference dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error if you aggregate before adding to the WHERE clause?

```
WITH 
SET [NewIDs] AS
    INTERSECT(
          NonEmpty(
             [ID].Children, 
             ([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old])
          )
        , NonEmpty(
             [ID].Children, 
             ([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD])
          )
        )
MEMBER [ID].[All].NewIDs AS
    AGGREGATE( [NewIDs] )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children
    ) ON 0
,
NON EMPTY([Dim1].Children
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE 
( [Measures].[Value]
, [ID].[All].NewIDs );
```

Try chucking the whole expression into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
     NON EMPTY([Dim2].Children) ON 0
    ,NON EMPTY([Dim1].Children) ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE 
( [Measures].[Value]
, AGGREGATE( 
  INTERSECT(
          NonEmpty(
             [ID].Children, 
             ([Date].&[T-1], [Category].&[Old])
          )
        , NonEmpty(
             [ID].Children, 
             ([Date].&[T], [Category].&[EOD])
          )
        )
 ) 
);
```

Comment: Yes I still get an error. The calculation of member `[ID].[NewIDs]` works fine, as I can select it on an axis, but placing it in the `WHERE` clause errors out.

Comment: Continues to error out with the expression in the `WHERE`